# in sharepoint 2013, .net library, or with REST, how do i get the regional settings of the current user?

Tags: .net, sharepoint, office365

I can easily get the regional settings for the web, but how do i do it for the current user?

`var regionalSettings = context.Web.RegionalSettings`
works but there is no `RegionalSettings` on `context.Web.CurrentUser`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code snippet:

```js
var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"/_layouts/regionalsetng.aspx?Type=User";
var lcid, cultureInfo, timeZone;

$.get(url,function(data){
  $(data).find("select[name$='LCID'] option:selected").each(function(){
      lcid  = $(this).attr("value");
      cultureInfo  = $(this).text();
  });
  $(data).find("select[name$='TimeZone'] option:selected").each(function(){
    timeZone  = $(this).text();
  });

  alert(lcid + "::" + cultureInfo + "::" + timeZone);
});
```

More information:
http://sympmarc.com/2014/08/20/detecting-the-current-users-regional-settings-with-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

What I end up doing-

I need the timezone to handle the dates of an upload file just after the upload. Since requesting current user's and web's `TimeZone` objects got pretty messy and took too much time I decided to conclude the time zone from file's modified property:

```
var fileModifiedDate = uploadedFile.ListItemAllFields.Modified; 
return Math.round(moment.utc(fileModifiedDate).diff(moment.utc(), 'hours', true));
```